# Remove Substring but Preserve Formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I have a small bit of code that will remove the substring *junk* from cells that I have selected:

```
Sub RemoveJunk()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
         r.Value = Replace(r.Value, "junk", "")
    Next r
End Sub
```

The code works, but it destroys the formatting of the characters that remain in the cells.  So if I start with:

[image]

I end up with:

[image]

Is there any way to avoid disturbing the formatting of the characters that remain ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Sub RemovePreserveFormatting(ByVal Where As Range, Expression As String, Optional ByVal Compare As VbCompareMethod = VbCompareMethod.vbBinaryCompare)
  Dim c As Range

  For Each c In Where
    Dim pos As Long: pos = 0

    Do
      pos = InStr(pos + 1, c.Value, Expression, Compare)
      If pos = 0 Then Exit Do

      c.Characters(pos, Len(Expression)).Delete
    Loop
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: GSerg, any chance of a sentence of explanation?

Comment: @TobyAllen Well it's pretty self explanatory - you find the position of the string in the cell's `Value` and manipulate the corresponding [characters range](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11331709/11683), because that's how you preserve character-level formatting in Excel.