# Excel VBA: Range.Characters.Delete on 255 character string

Tags: excel, vba

Any way to delete characters from a 255+ character string in a given cell, while maintaining formatting?

example:

```
Range("A1").value = "Lathe-CNC-Primary1 | Inspection-In Process1 | OV - Heat Treat0 | Deburring1 | Lathe-CNC-Primary0 | Honing0 | Lathe-CNC-Primary0 | Deburring1 | Inspection-In Process1 | OV - F.P.I0 | Inspection-In Process1 | OV - Nitride0 | Inspection-In Process1 | Grinding Thru Feed1 | Inspection-In Process0 | 0V - Coating0 | Inspection-Final0"



Range("A1").Characters(Start:=1, Length:=17).font.bold = True
Range("A1").Characters(Start:=17, Length:=1).delete 'Does Nothing
```

I am using the 1's and 0's in this string (comes from a SQL statement) to format the word it's attached to, then deleting the 1 or 0.

desired result for the string in Range("A1"):

> **Lathe-CNC-Primary** | Inspection-In Process1 | OV - Heat Treat0 | Deburring1 | Lathe-CNC-Primary0 | Honing0 | Lathe-CNC-Primary0 | Deburring1 | Inspection-In Process1 | OV - F.P.I0 | Inspection-In Process1 | OV - Nitride0 | Inspection-In Process1 | Grinding Thru Feed1 | Inspection-In Process0 | 0V - Coating0 | Inspection-Final0

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

not sure what's your actual goal

you could either

- use `Replace()` method after your formatting:

  ```
  With Range("A1")
      Replace what:="1 |",replacement:=" |", LookAT:=xlPart
      Replace what:="0 |",replacement:=" |", LookAT:=xlPart
  End With
  ```
- Use `Mid()` function:

  ```
  With Range("A1")
      .Value = Mid(.Value, Start:=1, Length:=17) & Mid(.Value, Start:=18) '<--| "deletes" character in position 18
  End With
  ```

Comment: The goal is to delete certain characters while maintaining per-character formatting in the cell. Assigning `Value` will certainly [not work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11331709/11683).

Comment: You clever to get the goal! Anyhow if you're right (as you're likely to be) then OP can take the "replace" option

Comment: To clarify, per character formatting is what I'm after as @Gserg mentioned. Deleting a character in a 255+ character string actually generates a "1004" Application error, and unfortunately it looks like the per character formatting is not maintained after a Replace or Mid function runs.