# What do FALSE and numbers mean in ACTIVE.CELL.FONT?

Tags: vba, excel

I recorded the VBA for changing "bc" in the cell to red color on Excel for macOS 15.39.

[image]

```
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "abc"
ExecuteExcel4Macro _
    "ACTIVE.CELL.FONT(""Calibri (Body)"",""Regular"",12,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,1,1,,,1,1,,4,2,0,2)"
ExecuteExcel4Macro _
    "ACTIVE.CELL.FONT(""Calibri (Body)"",""Regular"",12,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,1,3,,,2,2,,3,-16776961,0,0)"
```

I try to figure out what those FALSE and numbers mean in `ACTIVE.CELL.FONT(""Calibri (Body)"",""Regular"",12,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,1,3,,,2,2,,3,-16776961,0,0)`.

I know the first three are about font, but I don't know the rest of them.

I didn't find any document about it. Can someone explain or give me the link to the document? Thanks

Comment: Please stop using `ExecuteExcel4Macro`. They were obsolete when Excel 95 came out. I doubt this could have ever resulted from recording a macro. [Use `Characters(x, y).Font.Color`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11331426/11683) for changing color of individual characters.

Comment: @GSerg I recored it on Excel for macOS 15.39. I just checked on Windows, I just realized the VBAs are different. Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is:

```
ACTIVE.CELL.FONT(font, font_style, size, strikethrough, superscript, subscript, outline, shadow, underline, color, normal, background, start_char, char_count)
```

you should get the macrofun.exe file from the MS site which contains the Help file for XLM functions: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1465

Comment: Thanks, the number of parameters still does not match. (Unfortunately, I cannot use macrofun.exe, since I am running Windows 10, it shows the error `The Windows Help program is not supported in Windows 10, Windows Server 2012 or later versions of Windows Server. The Windows Help program is available for Windows Vista, 7, 8 and 8.1 only.`)

Comment: I can't help you then since that is the official MS help file. It may be a Mac peculiarity.